# MVC Routing Removes Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

My current routing configuration looks as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   namespaces: new string[] { "ChiDesk.WebUI.Controllers" },
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The problem I'm running into is that if I link to the below address:http://localhost:20220/Public/Book?id=c231e3aa-a317-4321-88ef-fe989356babc

The routing appears to remove the id parameter part. So the address in the browser is set to:
http://localhost:20220/Public/Book

This obviously causes a problem if you refresh the page as the id parameter is not included anywhere.

What do I need to change on my routing to sort this out?

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Routing seems ok to me. Except some other problems

Comment: is that all your routes? Or there are others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.

On my document ready function I was setting the history using `replaceState`. However I was using `window.location.pathname` property which does not include parameters.

Changing it to `window.location` has sorted this out.